# Isomorphism of affine algebras implies isomorphism of polynomial rings over related associated graded rings ( Exercise of E.Kunz )

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'd like some help solving Exercise 13 chapter V of the book

"Introduction to commutative algebra and algebraic geometry" by E. Kunz.

Let an affine algebra $\mathcal{A}$ over a field $K$ have two representations
        $$\mathcal{A} =K\left[X_1,\ldots, X_n\right]/ I=K\left[Y_1,\ldots, Y_m\right]/ J $$
        as homomorphic images of the polynomial rings $R:= K\left[X_1,\ldots, X_n\right]$ and $S:= K\left[Y_1,\ldots, Y_m\right]$. Prove that
 there is an isomorphism of graded $\mathcal{A}$-algebras $$\mathrm{g}r_I(R)\left[Y_1,\ldots,Y_m\right]\cong \mathrm {gr}_J(S)\left[X_1,\ldots,X_n\right],$$ where $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are all of degree one.

Hint: It is suffices to show that $$ \mathrm{gr}_{J'}(S')=\mathrm{gr}_I(R)[Y_1,\ldots,Y_m], $$

for $S'=k[X_1,\ldots\, X_n,Y_1,\ldots, Y_m]$ and $J'=IS'+(Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)S'$.

He mentioned above as a hint. Actually, I can prove the hint, but I can not see how this hint results the claim. Any guidance would be appreciated.